# Is it possible to delete all files in a directory using XML?

Tags: xml

Is it possible to delete all files in a directory but not the actual directory using XML?

Here's what I tried:

```
<TEST dir="D:\Users\NAME\Desktop\TEST" file="*.docx">
  <find find=". -name "*.docx"; -type f|xargs rm -f" />
</TEST>
```

Please tell me if it is at all possible to do this.

If not is it possible to run a Java file through a XML file?

Comment: Using XML and ... what else?

Comment: Your question doesn't currently makes sense. It is like saying you want to delete some files using French.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not. XML is a data format (or rather, it is a means of writing data formats). It is not a programming language.

You could encode instructions in an XML file and then write a program (in Java or any other language) that would read those instructions and do whatever you like with them (including run Java programs and deleting files).